# Can I use the SSD M.2 slot for a Wi-Fi card?

Tags: wifi, compatibility, m.2

My search engine queries turn up a lot of result for the reverse, whether it's possible to use the Wi-FI M.2 slot for an M.2 SDD (e.g. NVMe).

The computer I ordered has an NVMe M.2 slot and a 2.5 HDD SATA connector. Since I don't have any NVMe disks, I'm thinking of connecting my M.2 SATA SSD (which I currently use via an external USB enclosure) to the 2.5 HDD SATA connector using an M.2 to SATA adapter.

This leaves me with a single free M.2 slot. Is this NVMe M.2 slot compatible with, say, Intel AX20x0-based Wi-Fi cards? Can I use the SSD M.2 slot for a Wi-Fi card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I recommend the *[Sintech M.2 M-Key M.2 Key E Module,NGFF WiFi Card to M.2 Key M Adapter Card](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07WBXP632)*.

[image]

It is worth noting that under certain conditions PCI-e lane allocation may mean that if you use both M.2 slots, some PCI-e slots may have reduced (or no) bandwidth. As such, you may or may not actually get any benefit compared to using the "normal" PCI-e adapter card that's typically included with standalone Wi-Fi cards. If you can provide your exact motherboard, we can provide more specific information.

Comment: My just arrived Mini-PC is a BKHD G30B N5 (Guangfeng Network Technology) with a Celeron N5100 and chipset GF-1338NNP. The brand name is printed all over the motherboard, so I think it's an inhouse design. The motherboard has an NVMe and Mini-PCIe slot. The Mini-PC itself is advertised as a soft router. M.2 Wi-Fi cards, particularly for Wi-Fi 6 (AX), are much cheaper than their Mini-PCIe variants, so I'm trying (if possible) to go the M.2 route first

Comment: You could get a Mini PCI-e to M.2 adapter, if there's space?

Comment: Apparently that's the better workaround, if a WiFi M.2 module can't be connected directly to the NVMe M.2 slot. Anyway, thanks for the picture, for pointing out what I "overlooked", NVMe and WiFi M.2 modules are mechanically incompatible, as they're keyed differently.